# Dynamically Provision iot Device With Azure dps - Unexpected Failure. Python sdk

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am dynamically provision an iot device using the python azure-iot-device python package. I am using v2 and not 3.0.0b2. I can't even get that to compile.

Here's my python code trying to provision a device:

```
import asyncio
import os

from azure.iot.device.aio import (
    ProvisioningDeviceClient,
)
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=".env")

CONNECTION_STRING = os.getenv("IOTHUB_DEVICE_CONNECTION_STRING")
ID_SCOPE = os.getenv("PROVISIONING_IDSCOPE")
REGISTRATION_ID = os.getenv("PROVISIONING_REGISTRATION_ID")
SYMMETRIC_KEY = os.getenv("PROVISIONING_SYMMETRIC_KEY")
PROVISIONING_HOST = os.getenv("PROVISIONING_HOST")
# PROVISIONING_SHARED_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("PROVISIONING_SHARED_ACCESS_KEY")

async def main():
    print("Starting multi-feature sample")
    provisioning_device_client = ProvisioningDeviceClient.create_from_symmetric_key(
        provisioning_host=PROVISIONING_HOST,
        registration_id=REGISTRATION_ID,
        id_scope=ID_SCOPE,
        symmetric_key=SYMMETRIC_KEY,
    )
    provisioning_device_client.provisioning_payload = "<Your Payload>"
    provisioning_result = None
    try:
        provisioning_result = await provisioning_device_client.register()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"an error occurred provisioning the device -- {e}")
    finally:
        print(f"result -- {provisioning_result}")
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Exit application because user indicated they wish to exit.
        # This will have cancelled `main()` implicitly.
        print("User initiated exit. Exiting.")
```

The symmetric key is derived by using the enrollment group master key to compute an HMAC-SHA256 of the registration ID for the device. I simply followed the "Derive a Device Key" section in this guide -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-legacy-device-symm-key?tabs=linux&pivots=programming-language-python#derive-a-device-key

I keep getting 'Unexpected Failure' error. The code is so little that there's almost nothing to debug. I believe I followed the steps closely in setting up my iot hub and dps. Please let me know any suggestions

Comment: hello @Duck Dodgers able to connect and send end telemetry from the [provisioned device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-legacy-device-symm-key?tabs=linux&pivots=programming-language-python#derive-a-device-key)

Answer (score 0):

**The error message **‘Unexpected Failure’** is too generic to identify the root cause of the issue. However, there are a few things we can check to resolve the issue.**

- First, make sure that the connection string, ID scope, registration ID, symmetric key, and provisioning host are all correct and valid. Second, ensure that the device is not already provisioned.

[image]

[image]

- Create an IoT Hub and IoT device
- Create Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service
- Add IoT hub in (DPS) Linked IoT hubs.
- Manage enrollments with Add link to IoT hub.
- Enable IoT Edge on the provision device.
- Used this link for `az iot dps enrollment-group` from [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/dps/enrollment-group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-dps-enrollment-group-compute-device-key).
- Replace the your resourcegroupname, dpsname, [enrollment_id](https://i.imgur.com/w9kT2n9.png), [registration_id](https://i.imgur.com/sQlXvaE.png). It gives `derived-device-key` or `PROVISIONING_SYMMETRIC_KEY`.

  ```
    az iot dps enrollment-group compute-device-key -g {resource_group_name} --dps-name {dps_name} --enrollment-id {enrollment_id} --registration-id {registration_id}
  ```

[image]

- Used the same reference for Provision devices using a symmetric key enrollment group in DPS Azure IoT Hub Device [Provisioning Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-legacy-device-symm-key?tabs=linux&pivots=programming-language-python#derive-a-device-key)

[image]

**Code:**

```py
import asyncio
import os
import logging
from azure.iot.device.aio import ProvisioningDeviceClient
from azure.iot.device import exceptions
from dotenv import load_dotenv
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=".env")
CONNECTION_STRING = os.getenv("IOTHUB_DEVICE_CONNECTION_STRING")
ID_SCOPE = os.getenv("PROVISIONING_IDSCOPE")
REGISTRATION_ID = os.getenv("PROVISIONING_REGISTRATION_ID")
SYMMETRIC_KEY = os.getenv("PROVISIONING_SYMMETRIC_KEY")
PROVISIONING_HOST = os.getenv("PROVISIONING_HOST")
async def main():
    print("Starting the device provisioning process")
    provisioning_device_client = ProvisioningDeviceClient.create_from_symmetric_key(
        provisioning_host=PROVISIONING_HOST,
        registration_id=REGISTRATION_ID,
        id_scope=ID_SCOPE,
        symmetric_key=SYMMETRIC_KEY,
    )
    provisioning_device_client.provisioning_payload = "<Your Payload>"
    provisioning_result = None
    try:
        provisioning_result = await provisioning_device_client.register()
        print("Device successfully provisioned!")
        print("Provisioning result:")
        print(provisioning_result.registration_state)
        print(f"Device ID: {provisioning_result.registration_state.device_id}")
    except exceptions.ProvisioningError as pe:
        print(f"Provisioning failed with error: {pe}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred provisioning the device: {e}")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("User initiated exit. Exiting.")
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Provisioned status:**
[image]

Comment: I am trying to DYNAMICALLY provision any device that connects - or attempts to connect -  to my hub. Do I still need to create an iot device and Enable IoT Edge on the provision device?

Comment: yes @ 
Duck Dodgers according to Prerequisites from [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-legacy-device-symm-key?tabs=linux&pivots=programming-language-python#prerequisites)

Comment: Ahh I see. I'll try and get back to you. And if it works, I'll accept the answer. I really appreciate the input